# Как сделать наименьший буст при поиске по синонимам в elasticSearch в nest c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, elasticsearch

Есть словарь с синонимами, добавляю его при создании индекса:

```
private string[] synonyms = new string[]{
                                        "респ.,республика,респ",
                                        "обл.,область,обл",
                                        "д.,дом,д",
                                        "ул.,улица,ул",
                                        "г.,город,г",
                                        "к.,корп,корп.,корпус,к",
                                        "стр.,строение,стр",
                                        "район,р-н",
                                        "тер.,территория,тер",
                                        "с.,село,с",
                                        "пер.,переулок,пер",
                                        "пл.,площадь,пл",
                                        "пр-кт.,проспект,пр-кт"
                                        };
```

Создание самого индекса:

```
 public async Task CreateAddressHousesIndexAsync()
        {
            var existIndex = (await _elasticClient.Indices.ExistsAsync(_elasticSettings.AddressIndexHousesLevel)).Exists;
            if (existIndex)
                return;

            await _elasticClient.Indices.CreateAsync(_elasticSettings.AddressIndexHousesLevel, c =>
                c.Map<ElasticAddressHouseLevel>(d => d.AutoMap()
                        .Properties(w => w
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.Id)
                                .Analyzer("custom_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.DistrictName)
                                .Analyzer("custom_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.Country)
                                .Analyzer("custom_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.RegionName)
                                .Analyzer("custom_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.DistrictName)
                                .Analyzer("custom_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.LocalityName)
                                .Analyzer("custom_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.StreetName)
                                .Analyzer("custom_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.HouseNumber)
                                .Analyzer("custom_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.BuildNumber)
                                .Analyzer("custom_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Keyword(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.PostalCode)
                            )
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.Latitude)
                            )
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.Longitude)
                            )
                            .Date(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.ChangedAt)
                            )
                            .Date(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.CreatedAt)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    .Settings(s => s
                        .Analysis(z => z
                            .TokenFilters(tf =>
                                tf.Synonym("address_synonym",
                                    syn =>
                                        syn.Synonyms(synonyms) //тут передаю списки синонимов
                                )
                            )
                            .CharFilters(cf => cf
                                .Mapping("custom_mapping", p => p
                                    .Mappings(new[]
                                    {
                                    "ё => е",
                                    "Ё => Е"
                                    })
                                )
                                .PatternReplace("replace_dot", w => w
                                    .Pattern(@"\.")
                                    .Replacement(" "))
                            )
                            .Analyzers(q => q
                                .Custom("custom_analyzer", w => w
                                    .CharFilters("custom_mapping", "replace_dot")
                                    .Tokenizer("standard")
                                    .Filters("lowercase", "address_synonym")
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
            );
        }
```

При поиске в индексе на примере запроса "проспект Жукова", выдает выборку других проспектов, а искомый адрес "Проспект Маршала Жукова" оказывается внизу, как сделать, чтобы именно синонимы имели наименьший приоритет и я получил свой адрес первым, или лучше как указывать синонимы в фильтрах при запросе также с наименьшим бустом, не добавляя их при создании индекса?